# Make nested CSS flexbox wrap content vertically in Edge

Tags: html, css, flexbox, microsoft-edge

I'm using CSS flex to achieve the following layout:
- Two "rows" in a container with a fixed height
- First row has fixed height and do not grow
- Second row occupies the rest of the available height (i.e., container height minus first row height) and contains a long list of items which I need to fill the available height and then start wrapping in the X axis direction (with possible overflow).

Basically, what I want to achieve visually is this:
[image]

However, no matter what I try **in Edge** I get this (content do not wrap and stretches the height instead):
[image]
Chrome works fine and wraps correctly.

Is there something I can do to achieve this without setting the height to the second row? My understanding was that the row will occupy remaining height but would not grow more than that, but seems like Edge does not like it.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px black dotted;
}

.row-1 {
  border: 1px red solid;
  height: 3em;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.row-2 {
  border: 1px green solid;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-1">
   Menu here
  </div>
  <div class="row-2">
       <ul class="list">
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>    
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try min-height:0 on row-2

Comment: try `flex-wrap:wrap` for `.list` :)